# 5 select boxes, hide values on each selected item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have select boxes, I would like to hide (delete) items from options that are already selected:

```
<select name="gets" class="gets">
<option value="0">SELECT</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
</select>

<select name="gets" class="gets">
<option value="0">SELECT</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
</select>

<select name="gets" class="gets">
<option value="0">SELECT</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
</select>

<select name="gets" class="gets">
<option value="0">SELECT</option>
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
</select>
```

So if I choosed option 1 from 1st select box, it should disappear from the rest, if I choose option 3 on select box 4, it should disappear from the rest

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Say like below:

```
$('.gets').change(function(){
    var value = $(this).val();
    $('.gets').not(this).find('option[value="'+value+'"]').hide();
})
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/C7JJM/100/)

If you want to exclude for `SELECT` option say like below

```
$('.gets').change(function(){
    var value = $(this).val();
    if(value!=0)
        $('.gets').not(this).find('option[value="'+value+'"]').hide();
})
```

Comment: Can I add one more option, can I add a button to reinitialise the 5 select boxes, so I can retry again?

Comment: @AbuRayane use `append` to add one more option, & add this code to show all options again `$('.gets').find('option').show();`

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to find all the options with the same value in the other select's and hide them.
I would use something like this:

```
var selects = $('select');
selects.bind('change', function(e) {
    var val = this.value;
    //show all options
    selects.find('option').show();
    selects.each(function() {
        if(!this.value) return;
        //hide the selected value in the other selects
        selects.find('option[value="' + this.value + '"]')
                .filter(':not(:checked)')
                .filter(':not([value="0"])')
                .hide();
    });    

});
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/42o9hwhe/2/)

Comment: Thanks nxt, quite comlicated, but nice one

Comment: @AbuRayane it's a little more complicated than the other examples, but that's because it handles the case where the user changes their previous choice. For example, if you select 1, 2 and 3 in the first three selects the fourth only shows 4 & 5. When you then change value of the first select from 1 to 4 the fourth select is then updated to show 1 & 5. The other examples here only deal with the removal of options.

Comment: oh yeah, that's right, I did not notice that, thanks bro

Comment: I've noticed that if I reset, select boxes are not reset to select http://jsfiddle.net/aburayane/42o9hwhe/3/

Comment: Setting the attribute should work, but I would recommend to just set the value to 0 (the value of the option you want to show) instead. $('.gets').val('0'); http://jsfiddle.net/42o9hwhe/4/

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```
$("select").on("change", function(){
    var selectVal = $(this).val();
    $("select").not($(this)).find("option[value="+ selectVal +"]").remove();   
});
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/3wnovcfk/11/)